# file_put_contents and image url whitespaces

Tags: php

I have a problem with getting image from url. I'm using file_put_contents and I found that problem is white spaces in image url because images without any whitespace working.

The URL I'm getting image looks that:

```
/support/member_profile/16-New%20Image%20(With%20Logo)%20(Medium).jpg
```

I tried with urlencode() but it's still not working. If I echo encoded url I get:

```
%2Fsupport%2Fmember_profile%2F16-New+Image+%28With+Logo%29+%28Medium%29.jpg
```

How can I solve that problem? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I figured out that I would need to replace ONLY whitespaces with %20. When using urlencode it encode entire URL so that's why it's not working.

Any tip how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode) to convert `%20` into real spaces.
Then you can call `file_put_contents`.

Comment: You should never have to use urldecode as a url%20that%20contains%20spaces should, in PHP, already be decoded. I'm afraid the question might be a bit too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You should only URL-encode the filename, not the entire path including the slashes:

```
$path = '/support/member_profile/16-New Image (With Logo) (Medium).jpg';
$p = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$f = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$e = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

echo sprintf('%s/%s.%s', $p, urlencode($f), urlencode($e));
```

And, actually, you need to urlencode each *path-part* as well.

```
$path = '/support/member profile/16-New Image (With Logo) (Medium).jpg';
$p = explode('/', $path);

foreach ($p as $pp)
  $pathparts[] = urlencode($pp);

echo implode('/', $pathparts);
```